# How do I activate an effect if the URLs hash changes?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-hooks

I'm using Ionic 7 and React 18.  I would like to activate a different component in my container if the hash portion of the URL changes. I have tried doing this:

```
const MyContainer: React.FC<ContainerProps> = () => {
    ...

  useEffect(() => {
    // Set step based on the hash in the URL
    const hash = window.location.hash.substring(1); // Remove the '#' from the hash
    switch (hash) {
        ...
      case 'message':
        dispatch(setStep(StepsEnum.Message));
        break;
    }
  }, []);

    ...
        {step === StepsEnum.Name && <MyFirstComponent />}
        {step === StepsEnum.Address && <MySecondComponent  />}
        {step === StepsEnum.Message && <MyThirdComponent />}
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  )
}

export default MyContainer
```

Unfortunately, when I type in a different hash in my browser, nothing happens (at least, I don't see my useEffect getting called). Is it possible to activate a different component based on the URL's hash?

Comment: I don't see why you'd _expect_ that to cause a change. An empty dependency list means it gets called only _once_, on initial render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you use a router, such as React Router, that provides hook that track URL changes, you'll need to explicitly listen to the `hashchange` event.

**Example (click the links)**:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const MyContainer = () => {
  const [hash, setHash] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleUrlChange = () => {
      setHash(window.location.hash.substring(1));
    };
    
    window.addEventListener('hashchange', handleUrlChange);
    
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('hashchange', handleUrlChange);
    };
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <a href="#1">1</a>
      <a href="#2">2</a>
      <a href="#3">3</a>
      <a href="#4">4</a>
      {hash}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<MyContainer />);
```

```css
a {
  margin: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

You can extract the hash tracking code to a `useHash` hook (intended):

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const useHash = () => {
  const [hash, setHash] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleUrlChange = () => {
      setHash(window.location.hash.substring(1));
    };
    
    window.addEventListener('hashchange', handleUrlChange);
    
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('hashchange', handleUrlChange);
    };
  }, []);

  return hash;
};

const MyContainer = () => {
  const hash = useHash();
  
  return (
    <div>
      <a href="#1">1</a>
      <a href="#2">2</a>
      <a href="#3">3</a>
      <a href="#4">4</a>
      {hash}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<MyContainer />);
```

```css
a {
  margin: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Now you can trigger your `useEffect` with the `hash` produced by `useHash`:

```
const MyContainer = () => {
  const hash = useHash();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    switch (hash) {
        ...
      case 'message':
        dispatch(setStep(StepsEnum.Message));
        break;
    }
  }, [hash]);
```

Comment: You mention "unless you use react router ..." and I do have "@ionic/react-router" (7.0.0) installed, does that allow me to do something different than what you have detailed above?

Comment: Yep. React Router has a `useLocation` hook - [v5](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation), [v6](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-location). I think that ionic still uses React Router 5.

Comment: To put it all together, I would use the useLocation hook to listen for URL changes and wait until I have detected a hash change?

Comment: And use the hash as a dependency of `useEffect`.